# Place bootstrap always on top despite of data-placement

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my first post here so please excuse me if there is something i'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to get on some `bootstrap` today.

The `popover` of my `button` is only working for top even when the codes says
"data-placement="right".

My first guess was that the popover doesn't appear on the right because there is another element in the way. I tried to set the set the popover position to fixed and on the Z-position 1071 in the CSS but it doesn't helped out.

This is the button:

```html
<button style="position:absolute;top:116.5px; left:113px;" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
        <span style="font-size:5.0em;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </button>
```

I am grateful for any advice.

Comment: i would recommend using jsfiddle for this matter, vanilla stackoverflow snippet doesn't support libraries. Can you post a http://jsfiddle.net link?

Comment: like this?:
https://jsfiddle.net/vosytbcz/

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to add some JS to make it work.

Comment: This is it:
https://jsfiddle.net/aftpfasp/

This is the Bootstrap standart CSS, my whole Body and the JS from my Header. I hope this works. sorry for my incompetence. :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loose the

```
placement :top
```

on your javascript code and you should be fine.

This is probably happening because your javascript 'overrides' what you have declared on your html.

Comment: This was it. I really don't know where the "placement:top" in the JS came from. I actually just copied the it from the bootstrap website.
Thanks you very much.